# Algorithm to determine the regularity of a language

Tags: algorithms, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

[According to the answer provided by Janoma](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-about-regularity-of-a-language), there are several methods to determine the regularity of a language.

### Theorem

Let **L ⊆ Σ∗**. The following conditions are equivalent:

- **L** is generated by a **regular expression** (i.e., the definition of regular language).
- **L** is recognized by a **nondeterministic finite automaton** (Kleene).
- **L** is recognized by a **nondeterministic finite automaton without ε-transitions**.
- **L** is recognized by a **deterministic finite automaton** (Scott and Rabin).
- **L** is generated by a grammar **(N, Σ, P, S)**, where **N** is a finite subset of **Σ∗** (Frazier and Page).
- **L** is generated by a **left (resp. right) regular context-free grammar**.
- The index of the **Nerode relation ≡L** is finite (Anil Nerode, Linear automaton transformations, 1958). This is widely (and incorrectly) known as the **Myhill-Nerode theorem**. ≡L is the relation used to build the minimal DFA of a regular language.
- The index of the **Myhill relation ∼L** is finite (John Myhill, Finite Automata and the Representation of Events, 1957). ∼L is the relation used to build the syntactic monoid of an arbitrary language.
- The **syntactic monoid of L** is finite (consequence of Myhill's result). We note here that the syntactic monoid, apart from being defined by using relation ∼L, can be defined as a minimal monoid (in size) that recognizes **L as a preimage of a homomorphism**.
- **L** can be recognized by a **read-only Turing Machine** (trivial).
- **L** can be defined by a formula in **Monadic second-order logic over strings** (Büchi).

However, in none of these methods is there a clear, step by step process that can be followed to conclusively prove that a language is regular.

Does such an algorithm exist? Please provide the necessary references as well.

Comment: What would be the input of the algorithm?

Comment: It is not "trivial" that a read-only Turing machine accepts only regular languages. Note a TM may move in two directions. Also excursions into the empty part of the tape have to be accounted for.

Comment: @Steven I would assume the grammar of that language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course one would first have to specify the language to apply the regularity algorithm. Even for a rather restricted class of language specifications such an algorithm would be impossible.

It is undecidable, for a given context-free grammar, to decide whether it accepts a regular language.

Theorem 6.3 (c) in:
Bar-Hillel, Perles, Shamir, On formal properties of
simple phrase structure grammars. Zeitschrift für Phonetik, Sprachwissenschaft und Kommunikationsforschung 14 (1961) 143–172. doi [10.1524/stuf.1961.14.14.143](https://dx.doi.org/10.1524/stuf.1961.14.14.143)

Comment: The quoted reference has been OCR'ed at the publisher as "On formai properties oî simple phreise structure grammars". Moreover, it claims: Published Online: 1961-04.